# "Android SDK Manager" Closes when opened

Tags: java, android, sdk

As the title says, I installed the android SDK,
and when I open the manager it instantly closes.
When I open `android.bat` under \tools it says it's:

```
not recognized as an internal and external command
```

I assume this means that I need to add another enviorment variable (under path) but I don't know which one. This is what I have currently under path:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk;
C:\Program Files (x86)\android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\tools;
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\tools
```

Should I add more? Thanks for the help!

**SOLUTION: Uninstalling the jdk7 (x64) and reinstalling the (x86) Along with the android SDK installer, worked...**

Answer (score 1):

Try adding all the way up to the tools directory.

`C:\Program Files (x86)\android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\tools`

Then go to the command line and type `android` and then press enter

Comment: doesn't the: android\[whatever's here]\sdk                  Mean everything under \sdk?

Comment: Also, I just added it, and typed in 'android'. It says it's not recognized as an internal or external command.

Comment: did you close and re open the console after modifying the `PATH` variable?

Comment: Restarting the system makes the changes. Which I did.

Comment: Nope, I still get the same: not recognized internal and external command

Comment: if you run `dir /w/o` on the tools folder do you see `android.bat` listed?

Comment: I got the solution: uninstalling the jdk7 (x64) and reinstalling the (x86) Along with the android SDK installer, worked...

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest that you add the `platform-tools` directory to your path if you need to access binaries such as `adb`, etc

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\platform-tools
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: uninstalling the jdk7 (x64) and reinstalling the (x86)JDK, Along with the android SDK installer, worked...

Link to the installer: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download